# How to get the parent of a schema in Mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I'm writing a Node.js application which uses Mongoose as an ORM.

I have one model, called Event, and one schema, called Participant, which is stored inside of my Event schema as a subdocument. Problem is, I need to implement a method that should access parent's data. And there's no documentation about that (or I couldn't find any). How can I access parent's data from its children?

I've seen the usage of `$parent` a few times, but it didn't work for me. Also I've seed the usage of `this.parent()`, but this causes `RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded` for my example.

Here is my code sample:

```
const Participant = mongoose.Schema({
// description
});

const eventSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    applications: [Participant],
    // description
});

const Event = mongoose.model('Event', eventSchema);

Participant.virtual('url').get(function url() {
    // the next line causes a crash with 'Cannot get "id" of undefined'
    return `/${this.$parent.id}/participants/${this.id}`; // what should I do instead?
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually `this.parent().id` worked:

```
Participant.virtual('url').get(function url() {
    return `/${this.parent().id}/participants/${this.id}`;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// creating schemas
const ParticipantSchema = mongoose.Schema({});
const EventSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    title: {type: String, default: 'New event'},
    applications: {type: [Participant], default: []},
});

// creating models
const EventModel = mongoose.model('Event', EventSchema);
const ParticipantModel = mongoose.model('Participant', ParticipantSchema);

// creating instances
const event = new EventModel();
conts participant = new ParticipantModel();

// adding participant to event
event.applications.push(participant);

//accessing event title from participant. (parent data from child object)
const child = event.applications[0];
child.parent() // 'New event'
```

Answer (score -1):

Mongo no has parents, you need use aggregates in your object or create references to another collection.

or you can use mongoose subdocuments, see the documentation: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/3.0.x/docs/subdocs.html

Comment: The thing is I am already using subdocuments, check my code example.